# Weird Lambda behavior in string equality

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have an array of strings `obj[] values`, but trying to use equality seems to be different than what I might expect, can someone clarify this?

content of values is ["train","train"];

```
var first = values.First();

values.Skip(1).All(v => Equals(v, first))
false
values.Skip(1).All(v => v.Equals(first))
true

Equals(values[0], values[1])
true
Equals(values[1], values[0])
true

values.Skip(1).All(v => Equals(v, first) == true)
false
values.Skip(1).Any(v => Equals(v, first) == false)
true
```

Any clue why it returns false?

Edit1: I have wrote a unit test and it passes, I'm checking if the strings have different cultures as @Michael Randall suggested

[Equals implementation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If I put the strings in an array of objects `var values = new object [] {"train","train"};` and run your code I get the results `true
true
true
true
true
false`, so I can't reproduce. You have to edit the code in your question to include an entire program that produces the behavior that you describe and then we might be able to tell you what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TheGeneral answer is usually the correct one, but in my case restarting the machine removed this issue. my guess it was the debugger have a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem must be your input

***Note*** : You should consider doing proper string comparison. [Best Practices for Using Strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices-strings)

However as you can see with the appropriate input, your code actually works

```
var first = "train";
var values = new object[]{"train", "train"};
Console.WriteLine(values.Skip(1).All(v => Equals(v, first)));
Console.WriteLine(values.Skip(1).All(v => v.Equals(first)));
Console.WriteLine(Equals(values[0], values[1]));
Console.WriteLine(Equals(values[1], values[0]));
Console.WriteLine(values.Skip(1).All(v => Equals(v, first) == true));
Console.WriteLine(values.Skip(1).Any(v => Equals(v, first) == false));
```

**Output**

```
True
True
True
True
True
False
```

[You can test it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XZ8IkV)

Comment: @mortb invisible characters maybe, everyone who actually types `train` can't reproduce OP's problem

Comment: Try it with the character you get here:  [CodePen - zero width space copier](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/iLKwm)

Comment: @ErikKip: It might be invisible characters, but in the OP's example some comparisons seem to work. One way to find out what code points are in the string would be to write `string.Join(",", value[0].Select(c => (int)c))` and get the code points as numbers (separated by comma)

Comment: @mortb The results were indeed weird, and OP would have to test it himself or make the actual text available because we all can't reproduce it. At least not with characters I know :)

Comment: @ErikKip:Yes, there may be characters such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_joiner in his string :)